# How to display external image in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

My controller returns a string which is a url of an image of an external site.
How do I display that url on the view.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AngryHacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9382/angryhacker) is correct. I am just expanding AngryHacker's answer with some code example.

Add a property in your ViewModel for the image url and return it in the first get call. Then use it in the View. Thus you are avoiding an unnecessary http request to  to the action again

```
public class UserProfileViewModel
{
  public string DisplayName { set;get;}
  public string GravatarURL { set;get;}
}
```

and in your ACtionMethod,

```
public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
  UserProfileViewModel objVm=new UserProfileViewModel();
  objVM.GravatarURL="http://www.externalsite.com/image/tiyra.jog";
  //Set other properties also.

  return View(objVm);
}
```

and in the View which is strongly typed to your UserProfileViewModel,

```
@model UserProfileViewModel
<h2>"@Model.DisplayName </h2>
<img src="@Model.GravatarURL" />
<p>The image is loaded from @Model.GravatarURL</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the URL part of your model and just reference it in the View.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're missing the part where you have to HTML-encode your output with the <%: %> tag, a la:

```
<%: Html.Label(ViewData["PicUrl"].ToString()) %>
```

...or, if it's a string property on your model...

```
<label><%: Model.PicUrl %></label>
```